# What is the difference between baseName and archivesBaseName in gradle war plugin?

Tags: gradle, war

I was looking at gradle's [war plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War%3AarchiveName) docs when I noticed that there is 
baseName which defaults to archivesBaseName.  There is another [plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-info-plugin) which is using `archivesBaseName` instead of `baseName`. I wanted to suggest them to use `baseName` instead of default value but I am not sure what is the difference.

So what is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link you are referencing is for the `War` **task** not the plugin. The task has a property named `baseName` which is used for naming the archive created by the task. The [`archivesBaseName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:archivesBaseName) property on the other hand is a convention property added to the project by the 'base' plugin. This property is used as the default value for `baseName`.

Basically, the `archivesBaseName` property is set as the *project* level and `baseName` at the *task* level. Setting `archivesBaseName` will apply to all archive tasks (Zip, Jar, War, Ear, Tar) and can be overriden for individual archive tasks by setting the task's `baseName` property.